# Amazon S3 check if file is fully uploaded

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having two services, one which uploads to S3 in an asynchronous manner and the second service is a post-processor which does some additional processing on the uploaded files.

The problem I'm having is when the files are requested too fast in the second service, then the S3 Client thinks that the file exists because the key exists, but the whole file has not been uploaded yet so an exception is thrown.

It works if I perform blocking uploads, but the performance is pretty bad.

Is there some way to check if a file to S3 has been fully uploaded?

Comment: *"the S3 Client thinks that the file exists because the key exists"* You may want to inspect this more closely.  The key does not exist until the upload is complete, unless, if course, you are overwriting an existing object -- uploads to S3 are atomic, so the key for a new object does not exist until the upload conpletes successfully.

Comment: Could you please show us part of your code and also please tell us the exception which is occuring. Maybe it is a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable S3 Events on your bucket using the AWS S3 Console, then a file create complete event would be sent to tell you when the upload is complete.  The events may be published to SNS, SQS, or AWS Lamba.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix your key name with temp and then rename it to original file name after completion of upload, so that your next service will check for original file name and it performs the operation if the original file exists.

Comment: worth noting: rename or mv in s3 is actually performing copy+delete